# Google Chrome Extension - Is there a way to access current tab's DOM with JS files loaded in it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to create an extension which can access my applications DOM along with js files loaded (in my case it is EXT js).
I have a script which needs access to EXT js library, i'am able to run the script successfully in chrome console, but the extension is not able to pick it up.

Can anyone suggest me a good example to look at which can access the current screens loaded js files (like framework files like jquery,extjs,etc).

manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "MY APP",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "APP Only!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "web_accessible_resources": [
       "script.js"
    ],
 "content_scripts": [{
         "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
         "js": ["/js/content.js"]
     }
 ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "/images/abcd.png" 
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

content.js looks like this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

script.js looks like this:

```
function disBor(screen) {
   showCont(screen+' *[cont_]', 'red');  
   showCont(screen+' *[block_]', 'blue'); 
}
function showCont(selector, style) {
   //Ext is undefined below
   var conts = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(selector);
  });
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   disBor('#ABCD');
})
```

Comment: Yes, [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: The question is not about whether we can insert content scripts. That of course we can.

The question specifically is whether the inserted script can access the page's DOM **along with js files loaded in it** which it cannot.

Comment: @techfoobar, you've missed on both points. 1) The linked answer isn't about inserting a content script. 2) The question was if an extension can access the page context. The right answer is that it can and the linked answer shows how to do it: in short, by adding a DOM script element. –

Comment: Hello guys, added code snippet for more information on what iam asking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @wOxxOm, i tried "Method 1" in the link u provided. Unfortunately it did not work, not sure how to debug as well since we are not adding the code as background code!.
please let me know ur suggestions.

Comment: The code looks fine. To debug it add `debugger;` statement on the first line and reload both the extension on chrome://extensions page and the tab as well.

Comment: I guess you need to wait for the `load` event inside script.js e.g. window.addEventListener('load', () => { ............... })

Comment: @wOxxOm even i tried that without luck. Not even throwing error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203754/discussion-between-sujith-m-u-and-woxxom).

Comment: Make sure you've opened devtools before reloading the tab, otherwise `debugger` won't trigger. Anyway, this is now a purely how-to-debug or how-to-wait-for-script-load topic (for example, you can use a periodic check via setInterval/setTimeout).

Comment: BTW no need to wait for DOMContentLoaded because content scripts run afterwards anyway by default so your code may simply never run because of this unnecessary listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks a lot, that was really helpful. Is it possible to call chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener from our injected script (script.js) or from content script file content.js, in order to make the extension work on click only?

Comment: No, you need a background script for chrome.browserAction.

Comment: @wOxxOm By using background script, will the extension be able to access the page content, like the extjs or jquery loaded in the page.

Comment: No, it runs in a separate hidden page. See the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).